# Counter busy waiting

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

To implement graceful termination of an `AsynchronousFileChannel`, I must wait for all submitted tasks to finish execution before calling its `close()` method.
I can not shutdown and await termination of the underlying executor, because of the `close()` method requirements outlined in the Javadoc.

Therefore I'm trying to do the following, except I don't know how to properly implement it.

**Thread 1, 3, 4, ...**

```
counter.increment();
// Schedule task
```

**Thread 2**
(managed by an executor service)

```
// Task completed
counter.decrement();
```

**Thread 1**
(sometime in the future)

```
while (!counter.isZero()) {
    // Wait
}
// Proceed
```

If possible, tasks that arrive while waiting should be accepted. Subsequent tasks should be discarded, possibly triggering some logic.

---

Putting `Future`s in a `BlockingQueue` would be overkill, because counting queued plus running tasks could suffice in this case.

Which class in the `java.util.concurrent` package should I use?

Comment: Why can't you shutdown the executor? What are "the close() method requirements outlined in the Javadoc."?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt The executor is shut down after the `close()` method is called, but all pending tasks must be processed before calling the `close()` method.

Comment: Why don't you close it after shutting down the executor?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Because _shutting down the executor service while the channel is open results in unspecified behavior_ ([see here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousFileChannel.html#open(java.nio.file.Path,java.util.Set,java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService,java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...))).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked into your assertions about the `close()` methods, but you can use a semaphore to create a sort of gateway that locks on demand:

```
final Semaphore gate = new Semaphore(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

void submit() {
    if (gate.tryAcquire()) {
        try {
            // submit
        } finally {
            gate.release();
        }
    }
}

void shutdown() throws InterruptedException {
    gate.acquire(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    // shutdown
}
```

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure it's a good idea to try to acquire all permits at once. You might need to make it fair to prevent starvation. Or acquire permits in a loop (until what?). Or consider a ReadWriteLock.

Comment: I thought `acquire(Integer.MAX_VALUE)` would do so incrementally, that is, try to acquire each permit as it became available. But looking at the code, it's all or nothing. Which means if there's a lot of concurrent traffic it may never succeed. It's possible that creating the semaphore in [fair](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#isFair--) mode would prevent that.

Comment: Actually, I'm not so sure it's all or nothing. The code is a little esoteric.